# How to create multiple unnamed pipes dynamically?

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, fork

Say we have N child processes from the same parent. Is there a way, based on how many child processes there are, to **create multiple pipes** without using multiple declarations?

Avoiding something like this:

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
int fd2[2];
pipe(fd2);
int fd3[2];
pipe(fd3);
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dynamically sized array, then call `pipe()` once for each child process.

```
int *fds = malloc(2*n * sizeof *fds);

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    pipe(&fds[i * 2]);
}
```

Comment: And now how can I access to one of the i `fds` pipe with two single child processes?